# Cocoa: How to bind a boolean property to NSCellStateValue?

Tags: cocoa, state, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield, nsvaluetransformer

I would like to bind the boolean `enabled` property of an `NSTextField` to the state of an `NSButton`. I already tried adding a custom `NSValueTransformer` that transforms the state of the `NSButton` into `NSNumber`. However, in that scenario the text fields are disabled all the time for some reason. My second approach: To bad fails also since `NSValueTransformer` does not offer return primitives types such as `BOOL`.

**Example:**
The screenshot shows an example in which the text fields are disabled because the checkbox has the state `NSOnState`. I also would like to bind the labels to this state.

[image: Disabled text fields]

Further, it would be convenient, if I could **set a "disabled text" in Interface Builder**. In the above example I set the text in the associated class.

---

**Edit:**

I set `self.anonymousLoginCheckbox.state` as the *Model Key Path* for the *enabled* property of the account text field. Similar for the password text field. However, it does **not** work.

[image: Interface Builder Binding]

---

**Update:**

I created an [example project available on GitHub showing the implementation](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/CustomTextField) kindly described by Nicolas Bachschmidt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NSButton` isn't KVO compliant for the key `state`. Cocoa Bindings require the observed object to emit notifications when the observed property changes. As `NSButton`'s `state` is just a wrapper for its cell's `state`, `-[NSButton setState:]` method (and the automatic KVO notifications) isn't invoked when the user click the button (but `-[NSCell setState:]` is). If you set the model key path to `self.anonymousLoginCheckbox.cell.state`, it will work.